# Setting up Impala with Spring Batch Issues

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am attempting to setup Impala with a Spring Boot Spring Batch project. I am doing this by setting up Impala as a "non-standard" database. However, I am running into issues doing so and am not quite sure what config I'm getting wrong here:

ImpalaConfig.java:

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("impala.datasource")
@Getter
@Setter
public class ImpalaConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {
    public String url;
    public String username;
    public String password;
    public String driverClassName;
    public String threadNum;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;


    public ImpalaConfig() {
        super();
    }

    public ImpalaConfig(DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        factory.setDatabaseType("ORACLE");
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate impalaJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        System.out.print("Printing datasource object " + dataSource);
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
impala.datasource.url=jdbc:impala:{impaladatabase url}
impala.datasource.username={user}
impala.datasource.password={pass}
impala.datasource.driver-class-name=com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver
impala.datasource.threadNum=1
```

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
2019-03-19 13:41:36.049  WARN 35240 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.a.DefaultBatchConfigurer       : No datasource was provided...using a Map based JobRepository
2019-03-19 13:41:36.084  INFO 35240 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
Printing datasource object HikariDataSource (null)2019-03-19 13:41:36.848  INFO 35240 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-03-19 13:41:36.852  WARN 35240 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2019-03-19 13:41:37.703  INFO 35240 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (Feature not implemented: No details.)
```

Along with stack trace:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-03-20 13:41:13.481 ERROR 19068 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchConfigurer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to initialize Spring Batch
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:139) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:419) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1737) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.javasampleapproach.batch.parallelstep.SpringBatchParallelStepApplication.main(SpringBatchParallelStepApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to initialize Spring Batch
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BasicBatchConfigurer.initialize(BasicBatchConfigurer.java:101) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:363) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DatabaseType not found for product name: [Impala]
    at org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType.fromProductName(DatabaseType.java:82) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType.fromMetaData(DatabaseType.java:121) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:183) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BasicBatchConfigurer.createJobRepository(BasicBatchConfigurer.java:131) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BasicBatchConfigurer.initialize(BasicBatchConfigurer.java:96) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Comment: It looks like your `ImpalaConfig` is not being taken into account. You have set `factory.setDatabaseType("ORACLE");` but the log says `DatabaseType not found for product name: [Impala]`. From what you shared, I don't see how you can get this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need  to remove `@Bean` on the `createJobRepository()` method. Since you are overriding a method which does not declare the result as a bean, you don't need to add `@Bean` on it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Made the change but I'm still seeing the same error

Comment: What you are showing as an error is not an error.   Those are just INFO and WARN log statements.   Is there and actual ERROR log entry?   You said there is a stack trace, but you did not provided it.   That should be included in the post.

Comment: Apologies.. it didn't paste in there for some reason. Just added